# Group items in a list and calculate sums

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list with weekly figures and need to obtain the grouped totals by month.

The following code does the job, but there should be a more pythonic way of doing it with using the  standard libraries.
The drawback of the code below is that the list needs to be in sorted order.

```
#Test data (not sorted)
sum_weekly=[('2020/01/05', 59), ('2020/01/19', 88), ('2020/01/26', 95), ('2020/02/02', 89),
 ('2020/02/09', 113), ('2020/02/16', 90), ('2020/02/23', 68), ('2020/03/01', 74), ('2020/03/08', 85),
  ('2020/04/19', 6), ('2020/04/26', 5), ('2020/05/03', 14),
 ('2020/05/10', 5), ('2020/05/17', 20), ('2020/05/24', 28),('2020/03/15', 56), ('2020/03/29', 5), ('2020/04/12', 2),]

month = sum_weekly[0][0].split('/')[1]
count=0
out=[]
for item in sum_weekly:
    m_sel = item[0].split('/')[1]
    if m_sel!=month:
        out.append((month, count))
        count=item[1]
    else:
        count+=item[1]
    month = m_sel
out.append((month, count))

# monthly sums output as ('01', 242), ('02', 360), ('03', 220), ('04', 13), ('05', 67)
print (out)
```

Comment: Just to make sure: you want to group by dates, which are the first element of the (date, num) tuple, and calculate the sum of numbers, which are the second element of the (date, num) tuples, for each date group?

Comment: @Liorr the first element of the tuple represents the month. ```(04,13)``` means 13 in April

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `defaultdict` to store the result instead of a list. The keys of the dictionary would be the months and you can simply add the values with the same month (key).

Possible implementation:

```py
# Test Data
from collections import defaultdict

sum_weekly = [('2020/01/05', 59), ('2020/01/19', 88), ('2020/01/26', 95), ('2020/02/02', 89),
              ('2020/02/09', 113), ('2020/02/16', 90), ('2020/02/23', 68), ('2020/03/01', 74), ('2020/03/08', 85),
              ('2020/03/15', 56), ('2020/03/29', 5), ('2020/04/12', 2), ('2020/04/19', 6), ('2020/04/26', 5),
              ('2020/05/03', 14),
              ('2020/05/10', 5), ('2020/05/17', 20), ('2020/05/24', 28)]


results = defaultdict(int)
for date, count in sum_weekly: # used unpacking to make it clearer
    month = date.split('/')[1]
    # because we use a defaultdict if the key does not exist it
    # the entry for the key will be created and initialize at zero
    results[month] += count

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (it is part of standard library) - it does pretty much what you did under the hood (grouping together sequences of elements for which the key function gives same output). It can look like the following:

```
import itertools

def select_month(item):
    return item[0].split('/')[1]

def get_value(item):
    return item[1]

result = [(month, sum(map(get_value, group))) 
            for month, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(sum_weekly), select_month)]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Terse, but maybe not that pythonic:

```
import calendar, functools, collections

{calendar.month_name[i]: val for i, val in functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, [collections.Counter({datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y/%m/%d').month: val}) for time, val in sum_weekly]).items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

a method using pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

l = sc.parallelize(sum_weekly)

r = l.map(lambda x: (x[0].split("/")[1], x[1])).reduceByKey(lambda p, q: (p + q)).collect()

print(r) #[('04', 13), ('02', 360), ('01', 242), ('03', 220), ('05', 67)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a Pandas dataframe. First, you isolate the month, and then use groupby.sum().

```
import pandas as pd

sum_weekly=[('2020/01/05', 59), ('2020/01/19', 88), ('2020/01/26', 95), ('2020/02/02', 89), ('2020/02/09', 113), ('2020/02/16', 90), ('2020/02/23', 68), ('2020/03/01', 74), ('2020/03/08', 85), ('2020/04/19', 6), ('2020/04/26', 5), ('2020/05/03', 14), ('2020/05/10', 5), ('2020/05/17', 20), ('2020/05/24', 28),('2020/03/15', 56), ('2020/03/29', 5), ('2020/04/12', 2)]

df= pd.DataFrame(sum_weekly)
df.columns=['Date','Sum']
df['Month'] = df['Date'].str.split('/').str[1]
print(df.groupby('Month').sum())
```